# If there is a surjection $A\to B $ and another $B\to A$ then $A $ and $B$ are in bijection

Tags: functions, set-theory

I am trying to prove this (it looks true to me) :

Let $A,B $ be two sets. If there is a surjection $A\to B $ and a surjection $B\to A$ then $A $ and $B $ are in bijection.

I showed that is it equivalent to the following statement :

If there is an injection $A\to B $ and an injection $B\to A$ then $A $ and $B $ are in bijection.

But I am stuck, I don't see how to prove either.

Comment: Ho w did you show the equivalence to the statement involving injections?

Comment: If we have a surjection $f:A\to B $ then, for each $b \in B $ we can (via the axiom of choice) choose an element $a\in f^{-1}(b) $. Then we have an injection  $g:B\to A $ by defining $g  (a)=b $ (we do that for every $b $).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion that if there are *injections* $A \leftrightarrows B$ then there is a bijection $A \to B$ is the [Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) and has a reasonably involved proof—involved enough that I doubt you'd reasonably be expected to prove it yourself.

Every surjection $f : A \to B$ has a right inverse $r : B \to A$, i.e. a function such that $f(r(b))=b$ for all $b \in B$, and this right inverse is injective. You have (in the comments to your question) correctly constructed such a right inverse and identified that it is injective, and so the result follows from the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem... that is, if you're allowed to assume it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't knew it was a famous theorem.

Comment: It should be noted that the existence of the right inverse is equivalent to the axiom of choice, while the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem can be proved without it.

Comment: Clive Newstead-- I don't only do what I'm expected to do :)